# Getting : Error importing Spark Modules : No module named 'pyspark.streaming.kafka'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a requirement to push logs created from pyspark script to kafka. Iam doing POC so using Kafka binaries in windows machine. My versions are - kafka - 2.4.0, spark - 3.0 and python - 3.8.1. I am using pycharm editor.

```
import sys
import logging
from datetime import datetime

try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
    from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

except ImportError as e:
    print("Error importing Spark Modules :", e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Getting error

> Error importing Spark Modules : No module named 'pyspark.streaming.kafka'

What is that I am missing here? Any library is missing? pyspark and spark streaming is working fine. I would appreciate if someone can provide some guidance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the versions I was using for python and spark. 
I was using python 3.8 which doesn't support pyspark completely. I changed version to 3.7.  Also spark 3 is still in preview, changed that to 2.4.5., it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Spark Streaming was deprecated as of Spark 2.4.

You should be using Structured Streaming instead via `pyspark.sql` modules

Comment: i am facing the same issue, i tried with almost all the version, but didnt figured it out. Yes it is deprecated but i cant understand why it will through the error.

Comment: @vishal Maybe because you're not adding `--packages` to include the module? Spark doesn't come with Kafka packages