# No module named 'pyspark.streaming.kafka' even with older spark version

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

In another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187069/getting-error-importing-spark-modules-no-module-named-pyspark-streaming-kaf), they hint 'install older spark 2.4.5.'

EDIT: the solution from above link says 'install spark 2.4.5 and it does have kafkautils. But the problem is I can't download spark2.4.5 - not available even in the archive.

i followed the advice, installed older version of spark - spark2.4.6(the only old available) and also have python37, kafka-python,pyspark libs.

i have my spark_job.py file that needs to use kafka

```
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
```

when hitting 'python spark_job.py

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.streaming.kafka'
```

the error still persists!

spark_job.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os
import shutil

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils # this is the problem
import json


outputPath = 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/kafka_project/checkpoint_01'


def getSparkSessionInstance(sparkConf):
    if ('sparkSessionSingletonInstance' not in globals()):
        globals()['sparkSessionSingletonInstance'] = SparkSession\
            .builder\
            .config(conf=sparkConf)\
            .getOrCreate()
    return globals()['sparkSessionSingletonInstance']

#-------------------------------------------------
# What I want to do per each RDD...
#-------------------------------------------------
def process(time, rdd):

    print("===========-----> %s <-----===========" % str(time))

    try:
        spark = getSparkSessionInstance(rdd.context.getConf())

        rowRdd = rdd.map(lambda w: Row(branch=w['branch'],
                                       currency=w['currency'],
                                       amount=w['amount']))
                                       
        testDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rowRdd)

        testDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("treasury_stream")

        sql_query = get_sql_query()
        testResultDataFrame = spark.sql(sql_query)
        testResultDataFrame.show(n=5)

        # Insert into DB
        try:
            testResultDataFrame.write \
                .format("jdbc") \
                .mode("append") \
                .option("driver", 'org.postgresql.Driver') \
                .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://myhabrtest.cuyficqfa1h0.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/habrDB") \
                .option("dbtable", "transaction_flow") \
                .option("user", "habr") \
                .option("password", "habr12345") \
                .save()
        except Exception as e:
            print("--> Opps! It seems an Errrorrr with DB working!", e)

    except Exception as e:
        print("--> Opps! Is seems an Error!!!", e)

#-------------------------------------------------
# General function
#-------------------------------------------------
def createContext():

    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafkaTransaction")
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

    broker_list, topic = sys.argv[1:]

    try:
        directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                                        [topic],
                                        {"metadata.broker.list": broker_list})
    except:
        raise ConnectionError("Kafka error: Connection refused: \
                            broker_list={} topic={}".format(broker_list, topic))

    parsed_lines = directKafkaStream.map(lambda v: json.loads(v[1]))

    # RDD handling
    parsed_lines.foreachRDD(process)

    return ssc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: spark_job.py <zk> <topic>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)
        
    print("--> Creating new context")
    if os.path.exists(outputPath):
        shutil.rmtree('outputPath')

    ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(outputPath, lambda: createContext())
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Can you run a `print(spark.version)` call to verify the Spark version that's being used?  Looked at the [PySpark 2.4.5 docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html) and they do contain a `pyspark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils` class.

Comment: @Powers that's the problem - i m using 2.4.6, not 2.4.5! and i tried to install 2.4.5 it's not exist on the downloads page, not even in archive!

Comment: PySpark [2.4.6](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark/2.4.6/) is in PyPi.  [KafkaUtils is also in 2.4.6](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html#pyspark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils).  You might want to try using a Python dependency management system like [Poetry with PySpark](https://mungingdata.com/pyspark/poetry-dependency-management-wheel/) to make sure you're working with a virtual environment that has the dependencies you need.

Comment: @Powers, thx i just downgraded using pip

Answer (score 6):

i just downgraded it using pip:

```
pip install --force-reinstall pyspark==2.4.6
```

I did not use any poetry. AFter reinstalling, the kafkaUtils pkg was recognized.

Comment: Is there any another way because i am missing some other finctionalities by down grading pyspark